# OTG disconnects when screen turns off

Tags: usb, usb-on-the-go, usb-drivers, disk-drive

I am using OTG external drive constantly. But it will always disconnect when the screen turns off. This causes data loss issues. I tried to find any related settings in system settings and developer options, but no luck. I tried to disable battery optimization etc.. None of them works.

Btw, I am running Andriod 10 (non rooted) (Sony model).

Do anyone know how to fix the issue or workaround it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: @alecxs thanks a lot for your reply. I think the problem is due to the built-in filesystem driver. I tried some third-party FAT32 and exFat drivers and they don't disconnect when screen turns off. But third-party drivers have some limitations, for example unable to really mount the drive on un-root device. I think I am out of luck on this device's built-in driver. Btw, the issue doesn't happen to all android devices. I think it's model specific issue.